# multilayer or nested session in mobile applications

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework  as a matter of course I use angular.js for front end. on the back end, I use spring-boot for data handling and API management. 
I have used a single session and csrf token exchange between client and server. 
However, I have been asked to use in some sections one extra security control. as an example one section of application can take as long as server is alive. Another section can stay alive till couple of weeks and another section will ask in every single request or every single.

How can I handle this design problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern webapps use [JSON Web Tokens (JWT)](https://jwt.io/introduction/)
there is also an [angular package](https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt) you can use.

These tokens are sent with every request and contain arbitrary information about the user or other data. They are issued by your API on successful login and stored in your frontend. The issued token is then attached to **every** request header when requesting your API. You can then in the backend decode the token and determine if the user has all the required rights to continue, if the token is still valid our outdated for your different use cases.

I am not familiar with your backend solution but i am sure you can find some jwt packages for it or implement an easy solution yourself. (Googling for [spring jwt](https://www.google.de/search?q=spring%20jwt) gave quite some results)